# Quasar / Vue / Electron Reload Current Page from Layout With Different Data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, quasar-framework

I have a Quasar & Electron app and I'm trying to use the router to refresh/reload the data on a page and I'm not sure how.

In my Layout, I have a select box where the user can select a dog (or a person), and clicking on that dog takes them to the dog details page.  That works just fine.
[image]

However, once the user is on the Dog Details page, and wants to switch to another dog using that select, the Dog Details page does not reload.  And this looks like it is as designed in Vue.

This is the method I'm using to go to the Dog Details page:

```
     async goDirectToDog(theDog) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'Dog Details', 
        params: {passDogID: theDog.value, 
        passType: 'fromDropDown'}
        })
    },
```

How do I tell my application to please re-query the database when a new dog is selected from the input in the layout and display the new dog? I'm not sure how or if I can use the routes to do this. Or if I need to approach it from a different direction.

It looks like the Dog Details page is not reloading at all, so I can't just re-query the database with the newly selected dog.

This is my routes.js:

```
{ 
        path: '/dogDetails', 
        component: () => import('src/pages/dogDetails.vue'),
        name: 'Dog Details',
        params: true,
      },
```